# aws s3 uploading a directory to a bucket with php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-s3

This is the php file named upload.php in ec2 server

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key' => 'aws-secret-key',
            'secret' => 'aws-very-secret-pass',
        ));
$dir = '/home/user/movies/history';
$bucket = 'my-unique-bucket';
$keyPrefix = '';
$options = array(
    'params'      => array('ACL' => 'public-read'),
    'concurrency' => 20,
    'debug'       => true
);



$client->uploadDirectory($dir, $bucket, $keyPrefix, $options);
```

When I execute the upload.php file in terminal returns fatal error like this,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/home/kaya/Resimler/transferet/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/Sync/UploadSyncBuilder.php:47                                             
Stack trace:



#0 /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/Sync/UploadSyncBuilder.php(47): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('/home/user/movie...', 12800)           
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php(557): Aws\S3\Sync\UploadSyncBuilder->uploadFromDirectory('/home/user/movie...')                    
#2 /var/www/html/upload_dir.php(21): Aws\S3\S3Client->uploadDirectory('/home/user/movie...', 'my-unique-bucket', '', Array)                                                 
#3 {main}



  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/Sync/UploadSyncBuilder.php on line 47
```

Normally I can upload files clearly with php sdk except uploadfolder function. I couldnt find where is false. My php sdk version is 2.7.

Comment: Error seems pretty clear. `failed to open dir: No such file or directory` Either the directory doesn't exist, or your script doesn't have permissions to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It works on local server like xampp or something, doesnt work on remote server.

Comment: Sure it does. There's nothing magical about a local server. You're messing up something, likely the permissions of the directory aren't right.